# Swift dropDown library

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am using the dropdown library. When you press a button, you want to develop it in a format where text changes on the button when you click an element.I can print but I don't know how to change the text of the button. And I want to change the sort order of the table view when I click that element. How should I do it?

```
    func dropDown() {
        sequenceDropDown.dataSource = ["Latest order
", "Priority"]
        sequenceDropDown.show()
        sequenceDropDown.anchorView = sequence
        sequenceDropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y:(sequenceDropDown.anchorView?.plainView.bounds.height)!)
        sequenceDropDown.selectedTextColor = .white
        sequenceDropDown.selectionBackgroundColor = .mainColor
}
```

This is dropDown function.

```
  output.loadData.bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "mainCell", cellType: MainCell.self)) { row, element, cell in
            cell.nameLbl.text = element.nickname
            cell.titleTxtField.text = element.title
            cell.contentTxtView.text = element.description
            cell.postImage.image = UIImage(named: element.media)
            cell.timeLbl.text = element.date
            cell.sirenBtn.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: { _ in
                self.selectIndexPath.accept(row)
            }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
            
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This is binding tableview code.

Answer (score 0):

setting button's title is easy `myButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)`

if you want to change sort of table view, you probably should map `loadData` observable to needed sort method, maybe it's even better to store ouput from loadData to some array and wrap it to observable or subject, bind it to table view and if you need to see sorted tableview just sort the array

(maybe I didn't get you case point completely)